# Assigning pointer as argument to class variable and then using it throws read access violation

Tags: c++

I don't know if what I am giving is enough information, but because I am at a loss somehow I figured I might ask anyway.

I have a similar setup like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    SomeClass* someClass;

    A(SomeClass* someClass) : someClass(someClass) {}

    void DrawFunction()
    {
        someClass->DoSomething(); // <-- Read Access Violation
    }
}
```

And for some reason it throws a read access violation and as far as I know the original `SomeClass` does still exist. I can use it like I want in the constructor but not in the draw function for some reason.

A thing to note is, that the `DrawFunction` is in a different thread, but in the same thread I am using the `SomeClass` somewhere else.

Is there anything wrong with my code, or do I need to give more code in order to see what's wrong with it?

Comment: That's not enough code to diagnose the problem. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide such code that it can be compiled.

Comment: Can you show members of `SomeClass` too?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, the `DoSomething` method implemented as no public? For example like this:

```
class Foo {
     void DoSomething(){}
protected:
     void DoOtherthing(){}
}
```

If you will try to access for the `DoSomething` or `DoOtherthing` outside the Foo class and no from `friend`, you will have a similar error.

Comment: I am using a framework and basically the whole SomeClass is from that framework, but i don't really know yet what the issue is, because it only doesn't work in that context. It might be related to threads. You can see my answer i posted to see more code :D

Answer (score -3):

You have a resource contention. The resource `someClass` which is being accessed by multiple threads. use synchronization constructs such as `mutex`, `semaphore` etc for `someClass` (shared resource).

Comment: Oh yeah, that could actually be. I posted an answer, because i could get it to work without threads so i might check this out next.